# Requesting multiple pages on the same route | Python, Flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to request 2 pages (page and page2) to paginate 2 boxes on my website.

However, I'm getting an error like below:
[image]

Here are my entire codes:

```
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    comment_blogs1 = BlogInfo.query.filter(BlogInfo.blog_post_id.ilike(blog_validated_id)).order_by(BlogInfo.date.desc())
    comment_blogs = comment_blogs1.paginate(page=page, per_page=2)
    comment_blogs_num = comment_blogs1.count()

    page2 = request.args.get('page2', 1, type=int)
    ideas1 = BlogIdea.query.filter(BlogIdea.blog_post_id.ilike(blog_validated_id)).order_by(
        BlogIdea.date.desc())
    ideas = ideas1.paginate(page2=page2, per_page2=2)
    ideas_num = ideas1.count()
```

I don't know why I'm wrong as I already named 2 pages with 2 different names.

Answer (score 1):

the way you wrote it, paginate assumes a named parameter page2, which apparently is not available. Read the actual exception you are getting

Comment: Thank you! You helped me found the solution!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I changed my codes:

```
ideas = ideas1.paginate(page2=page2, per_page2=2)
```

into:

```
ideas = ideas1.paginate(page=page2, per_page=2)
```

The variable page, per_page could not be changed, it could only be reattributed to another variables.